How to modify the quantum circuit to do superdense coding with the state $|00\rangle-|11\rangle$?
Suppose I want to perform the superdense coding protocol, but instead of using the state $\beta_{00}=\frac{1}{\sqrt2}(|00\rangle+|11\rangle)$, I have to initialize it with the state $\beta_{10}=\frac{1}{\sqrt2}(|00\rangle-|11\rangle)$. Would it be as simple as applying an initial $Z$ gate on the top wire to change $\beta_{10}$ to $\beta_{00}$ and proceed as normal?

It could be, yes, depending on whether you want the sender or the receiver to adjust their part of the protocol. Either of them applying a $Z$ gate to their half of the pair before proceeding with the rest of the protocol will change it to $\beta_{00}$.

In order to encode two bits $x, z\in\{0,1\}$ using vanilla superdense coding protocol, we apply two Paulis to one of the qubits in a Bell pair
\begin{align}
|\beta_{zx}\rangle=(Z^zX^x\otimes I)|\beta_{00}\rangle.\tag1
\end{align}
But $|\beta_{10}\rangle=(Z\otimes I)|\beta_{00}\rangle$, so
\begin{align}
|\beta_{zx}\rangle=(Z^{z+1}X^x\otimes I)|\beta_{10}\rangle.\tag2
\end{align}
This means that superdense coding protocol can use $|\beta_{10}\rangle$ directly, rather than having it first converted to $|\beta_{00}\rangle$, at the cost of simple classical pre- or post-processing. Namely, we flip the $z$ bit before encoding or we flip it after decoding.
This generalizes to
\begin{align}
|\beta_{zx}\rangle=(Z^{z+a}X^{x+b}\otimes I)|\beta_{ab}\rangle\tag3
\end{align}
for any $a,b\in\{0,1\}$, which shows that any Bell state can be used in superdense coding at the cost of simple classical pre- or post-processing of the input/output bits. At least one of the parties must know the identity of the Bell state used.
